# Parse logs and print certain fields in a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file that I need help parsing

This is what it looks like:

```
2018-02-19 15:55:50.070 t.a.ApiUploader [INFO] zzz(708473232) uploaded file 'hdfs://fr-de.int.fz.net:4010/user/profile_export/aId=6/empId=4/classId=10/members-x--491eedd6-2e14-488f-8c13-84be2c6f777b.txt.gz' in 4 chunk(s) - total ops: 31, failed ops: 0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.092 t.a.ApiUploader [INFO] zzz(617022301) uploaded file 'hdfs://fr-de.int.fz.net:4010/user/profile_export/aId=6/empId=4/classId=10/members-x-de10af80-4ac5-4b1a-9675-f7aa9da7ecb2.txt.gz' in 5 chunk(s) - total ops: 45, failed ops: 0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.204 t.a.ApiUploader [INFO] zzz(89993157) uploaded file 'hdfs://fr-de.int.fz.net:4010/user/profile_export/aId=6/empId=4/classId=10/members-x-2aa7808e-a209-4bf8-a744-818724cca054.txt.gz' in 4 chunk(s) - total ops: 32, failed ops: 0
```

Now what am trying to do is put results of my parsing in an excel file like:

**Expected Output:**

```
Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops
2018-02-19 15:55:50.070,6,10,31,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.092,6,10,45,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.204,6,10,32,0
```

I can get it separately but how can I combine all into comma separated format? Is there a bash sample to do this?

cat twr.log | awk -F" " {'print $8'} | awk -F"/" {'print $8, $10'}

This gave me:

```
aId=6 classId=10
aId=6 classId=10
aId=6 classId=10
```

For date I did this:

cat twr.log | awk -F" " {'print "Date: " $1,$2'}

```
Date: 2018-04-19 15:55:50.070
Date: 2018-04-19 15:55:50.092
Date: 2018-04-19 15:55:50.204
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer illustrates the self-documenting power of creating/passing variables to keep track of fields:

```
awk -v OFS=',' -v date=1 -v time=2 -v url=8 -v url_aid=6 -v url_cid=8 -v total=15 -v failed=18 '
    NR == 1 { print "Date", "aId", "classId", "total ops", "failed ops" }
    {
        split($url, arr, /\//)
        aid = arr[url_aid]; sub(/[^=]+=/, "", aid)
        cid = arr[url_cid]; sub(/[^=]+=/, "", cid)
        sub(/,/, "", $total)
        print $date " " $time, aid, cid, $total, $failed
    }' twr.log
```

Couple of comments...

- The header is separated out on purpose in case `OFS` is changed in the future
- `$total` is sanitized prior to `print` for the same reason as we have for separating out the header, but also because in the alternate version such a subtle thing as a missing comma between `$total` and `$failed` is easy to gloss over in the reading.
- The above solution is easy to work on and think about if there is a need to modify in the future. For instance...

If the link is not fixed, or if filtering is required, something like the following would be more appropriate:

```
awk -v OFS=',' -v date=1 -v time=2 -v url=8 -v total=15 -v failed=18 '
    NR == 1 { print "Date", "aId", "classId", "total ops", "failed ops" }
    NF == failed {
        aid = cid = ""
        n = split($url, arr, /\//)
        for (i = 4; i <= n; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] ~ /^aId=/)
                aid = arr[i]
            else if (arr[i] ~ /^classId=/)
                cid = arr[i]
            if (aid != "" && cid != "") {
                gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", aid)
                gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", cid)
                gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $total)
                print $date " " $time, aid, cid, $total, $failed
                next
            }
        }
    }' twr.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked and will be using the not fixed solution!

Comment: Is there a way after printing the above result.. i can add up the failed and total ops display that?

Comment: @user175084 Sure!  **Awk** is very loosely typed, so you can just add anything to do a string to number conversion (and back again). First append another bit to the header `print` statement to describe your column, and then append `, $TOTAL + $FAILED` to the inner `print` statement.  One other thing... the exemplified simple filtering for `NF` and `aid`/`cid` may not be careful enough for what you want, and you may want to add some more criterion beyond `NF == FAILED`.

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names in awk (or shell) scripts - leave that for builtin variables (and exported ones in shell). Also, you don't have to manually set the FS to a blank char as that's its default value.

Comment: @Ed - I appreciate your input as you have been contributing on **awk** for much longer than I have, but I've found it useful in my scripts to differentiate passed params from internal variables.  From your experience, what is a good convention to use for passed params?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've never thought about doing that but maybe upper CamelCase for one (`Date` and `ClassId`) and lower underscore_separated for the other (`date` and `class_id`)? So you'd have `FileName` passed in, and `file_name` internally and neither would clash with the keyword `FILENAME`. You could even just use lower camelCase internally (`date`, `fileId`, `fileName`) but that's not such an obvious difference.

Comment: Thanks @Ed -- I'll think about it.   I will definitely consider what you have said, knowing that to many leveraging all caps for this may feel like "bad taste."   The more I write **awk** though the more I don't care about differentiating **awk** internal variables from passed params... On the other hand, visually differentiating passed params in my **awk** programs from other variables is of huge value to me.

Comment: A scenario to consider - right now you have a variable named `DATE`. Lets say in the next release the gawk maintainers decide to create a variable that holds the current date. They would probably name that variable `DATE`. Now when you get an update of gawk your script will fail to work and you'll have no idea why if you haven't been paying close attention to the release notes. There's already a LOT of built-in variables, especially in gawk, that I suspect few people really think about clashing with (e.g. `ERRNO`), see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables.

Comment: You convinced me @Ed... here’s your tolower().

Comment: @Ed -- even though I did the tolower() for people's tastes... I'm not fully convinced about the builtin variable case... Point of fact that GNU has added several functions, all lowercase -- such as strtonum(), and bit operations (I am trying to run some of my scripts with mawk now & ran into these as issues -- sigh).  It is impossible to know if GNU or any other flavor of Awk will add date() as a function or DATE as a variable in the future.  So, I'll use lowercase for vars in this forum to keep peoples eyes from bleeding, but I will continue to ponder about what to do in my company scripts.

Comment: @Michael if you have a variable name that clashes with a function name you'll get an immediate syntax error telling you what the error is and where it occurred and so you can easily and immediately fix it. If you have a variable name that clashes with a builtin variable name then you will get no warning, your script will just quietly, cryptically produce bad output that might take you weeks to notice and days of head-scratching to debug. That's why a clash of variable names is so much worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ /=,]"; OFS="," }
NR==1 { print "Date", "aId", "classId", "total ops", "failed ops" }
{ print $1" "$2, $14, $18, $26, $30 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops
2018-02-19 15:55:50.070,6,10,31,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.092,6,10,45,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.204,6,10,32,0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. THIS WORKS FOR SURE!!

Comment: Is there a way after printing the above result.. i can add up the failed and total ops display that?

Comment: Of course, that would be trivial but it looks like you already accepted an answer so - good luck!

Comment: With all due respect, but this is just a slightly modified copy of the answer given by @Cyrus.

Comment: Agreed. I thought about deleting it after I spotted that but I disagree with his use of `echo` with hard-coded commas to produce the header line outside of the awk script even if there was an empty input file so I decided to leave mine posted. I see he's deleted his now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you url is in fixed format

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'BEGIN{print "Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops"}
                     {split($8,a,"/"); 
                      sub(/.*=/,"",a[6]); 
                      sub(/.*=/,"",a[8]); 
                      print $1 FS $2,a[6],a[8],$15 $18}' file

Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops
2018-02-19 15:55:50.070,6,10,31,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.092,6,10,45,0
2018-02-19 15:55:50.204,6,10,32,0
```

otherwise, you have to pattern match within the elements of array `a` for the keywords you're interested in.

Note the hacks `$1 FS $2` and `$15 $18` for the special handling of the output delimiters for special cases

**UPDATE**

add this to the main block

```
sum15+=$15; sum18+=$18
```

and this as the last block in the script.

```
END {print "sum total ops:",sum15, "sum failed ops:",sum18}
```

Comment: Is there a way to print the above result. I want to add up the failed and total ops then display that?

Comment: Yeah seems to be an epidemic right now.... just happened over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/49902786/1745001 too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` function for this kind of cases:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS =","; print "Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops" } 
{ 
    match($8,/aId=([0-9]*)\/.*\/classId=([0-9]*)/,a)
    print $1 " " $2,a[1],a[2],$(NF-3) $NF 
}' YOURFILE
```

It might be more error-proof when format of URL is not very rigid.

Comment: You should mention thats gawk-only for the 3rd arg to match().

Comment: Yep, thanks. I use only `gawk`, so I don't know what other versions' equivalents would be. But I do believe this approach is more flexible than counting 30 fields by numbers. It works "gracefully" even in case of a missing URL.

Comment: Is there a way to print the above result. I want to add up the failed and total ops then display that?

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the regex in parens get captured as `$1` then `$2` etc...

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN{print "Date,aId,classId,total ops,failed ops"} \
print "$1,$2,$3,$4,$5" if /(\S+ \S+).+?aId=(\d+).+?classId=(\d+).+?total ops:\s*(\d+).+?failed ops:\s*(\d+)/' \
inputFile
```

As a side-note.  You can pipe the output of this (or some of the awk commands), like so:

```
| datamash -sHt , -g classId mean 'total ops' sum 'failed ops' | column ts ,
GroupBy(classId)  mean(total ops)  sum(failed ops)
10                36               0
```

To pull out the data you might be looking for in Excel.  Datamash is available for most package managers (`apt`, `pacman`, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Will be considering the datamash solution.. is there somethign similar in bash??

Comment: @user175084 built-in?  I don’t think so. But of course datamash is accessible from most bash shells. Probably MINGW would be the exception.

Answer (score 0):

No need to whip out the `awk`s and `perl`s for this small nugget. Here is a Bash-only solution :

```
while read date1 date2 _ _ _   _ _ url _ _   _ _ _ _ failed  _ _ total; do
  IFS=/ read _ _ _ _ _  _ _ aid _ classId _ <<< "$url"
  printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$date1 $date2" "$aid" "$classId" "$total" "${failed%,}"
done < file.log
```

Feels like Bash was made to parse CSV, doesn't it ? ;-)

Comment: Not even a little bit :-). That will be orders of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script and contains bugs (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice))

Comment: Perhaps that's the price of readability (no pun intended) :-) I know that the `read` builtin is not the fastest way to read text, but I like that it allows one to give legible names to the fields. I don't write Bash for performance or correctness (for that I have Haskell), I do it for the free cookies.