# Bash - Read portnumbers of certain service(s) into array

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, port-number

I'm searching for port numbers with grep (in a bash script)

```
portstr=$(lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep sshd)
```

portstr now looks something like this

```
sshd       673            root    3u  IPv4  14229      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       673            root    4u  IPv6  14231      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

now I want to extract the numbers between the colon (:) and the following blank space, to get something like this

portarray[0]=>22
portarray[1]=>22
thank you

I tried this

```
    var="[a1] [b1] [123] [Text text] [0x0]"
    regex='\[([^]]*)\](.*)'
    while [[ $var =~ $regex ]]; do
      arr+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
      var=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    done
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902786/extract-all-strings-between-two-characters-to-array-using-bash). But nothing really worked out.

Comment: `portarray=( $(lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN | grep -Po '^sshd.*:\K\d+') )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `awk` by setting the field separator to either 1 or more spaces or a colon using `[[:space:]]+|`

Check if the first field is `sshd`, the last field is `(LISTEN)` and then print the second last field:

```
portstr=$(lsof -i -P -n | awk -F"[[:space:]]+|:" '$1=="sshd" && $NF == "(LISTEN)" {print $(NF-1)}')
echo "$portstr"
```

For the output of `lsof -i -P -n` being:

```
sshd       673            root    3u  IPv4  14229      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       673            root    4u  IPv6  14231      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

The output of the command:

```
22
22
```

Reading [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449417/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-a-command-into-an-array) you can put the output of the command into an array:

```
portarray=( $(lsof -i -P -n | awk -F"[[:space:]]+|:" '$1=="sshd" && $NF == "(LISTEN)" {print $(NF-1)}') )

for port in "${portarray[@]}"
do
   echo "$port"
done
```

Comment: `portarray=( $(lsof -nPi -T -sTCP:LISTEN | awk -F: '/^sshd / && $0=$NF') )`